# Woocommerce - How to show/hide each FOREACH item, based on a condition outside of the LOOP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, foreach

So I have a script that is pulling information from the Woocommerce cart.

What is happening:

- If a wp_cache_get is successful, the script will initialize.
- Variables are created using a function that tells me how many items from a specific category are in the cart.
- I create an array that gives the names of my items (cartons of beer, by bottle amount) and the value, which is being pulled from my cat_cart_count() categories function.
- FOREACH loop begins, if the item has less than 4, it will create a message. If more than 4, another message.

But here is the thing. I need to be able to change that message if `$count` results in more than 1 item in the loop.

Reason being is, I don't want to repeat the same message over 3 times if they have 3 categories that fit the conditions ( `$pack_count < 4` ).

I'd like to be able to change the message if `$count` (outside of the loop, counting the items inside the loop) is greater than 2... For example:

```
if ( $count >= 2 ) {
    echo 'Oh wow, you have $pack_count in your cart. That is a lot of beer.';
}
```

And any other message would be hidden. This is basically a means of displaying many different messages inside the mini-cart, based on the items in the cart and their quantities.

Am I doing this the right way? How can I achieve this?

```
   // define the woocommerce_after_mini_cart callback 
   function action_woocommerce_after_mini_cart() {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

    $initialize = wp_cache_get( 'pack_building' );

    if ( $initialize ) {

    $the_six = cat_cart_count( "6" );
    $the_12 = cat_cart_count( "12" );
    $the_24 = cat_cart_count( "24" );

    $first_name = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_first_name', true );

    $packs;
    $packs["6-pack"] = $the_six;
    $packs["12-pack"] = $the_12;
    $packs["24-pack"] = $the_24;

    $count = 0;

    foreach( $packs as $name => $pack_count ){

        if ( $pack_count ) {

            $count_diff = abs( $pack_count - 4 );

            $count = $count + 1;

            //if less than 4 packs
            if ( $pack_count < 4 ) {
                $msg = "You have $pack_count - 7 boxes of $name";
                echo $msg;
            }
            //if more than 4 packs
            else {
                $msg = "You have over 4 - $pack_count of $name . You're saving big time!";
                echo $msg;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit hard to make sense of it all here. When you say you want the message `Oh wow, you have $pack_count in your cart. That is a lot of beer.` _after_ you gone through the whole loop - then what exactly is `$pack_count` supposed to refer to here? That is the count of _one_ of your individual packs - so _which one_ should that be here? Or did you actually mean `$count` here?

Comment: You should probably start by not echo-ing out the message(s) inside the loop, but collect them in an array instead. Then you can loop over that array in a second loop afterwards, if you want to output the individual messages relating to the individual packs now. Or you can output a different message altogether, instead of doing that second loop over the message array.

Comment: @CBroe sorry. $pack_count is counting the amount of items from that specific category. Essentially, I want to say "Oh you only need one more 6-pack to create a case of 24 craft beers" - However, if they have say 2 cases of Craft and 1 case of domestic beers, it would need to say "you're building 2 cases of beer" - which currently, I would have to use $count outside of the loop to count the amount of different categories in order to correctly know whether multiple categories were in teh array - does that make sense? Sorry if it is confusing... I myself am a bit confused.

Comment: Nah, doesn’t make much (more) sense to me. Especially since _“it would need to say "you're building 2 cases of beer"”_ appears to be a different requirement than what formulated before (_“Oh wow, you have $pack_count in your cart. That is a lot of beer.”_) But what I already said, still stands: If you want to potentially output a message _after_ the loop, that is supposed to replace those generated in the loop - then you can’t output them in the loop already, but need to gather them in a variable/an array first.

Comment: @CBroe dude - I know my explanation was super confusing - but your answer solved my issue! Creating an array works perfectly! Amazing, thank you!